# Google PubSub Java (Scala) Client Gets Excessive Amount of Resent Messages

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scenario where I load a subscription with around 1100 messages. I then start a Spark job which pulls messages from this subscription with these settings:

MaxOutstandingElementCount: 5

MaxAckExtensionPeriod: 60 min

AckDeadlineSeconds: 600

The first message to get processed starts a cache generation which takes about 30 minutes to complete. Any other messages arriving while this is going on are simply "returned" with no ack or nack. After that, a given message takes between 1 min and 30 mins to process. With an ack extension period of 60 min, I would never expect to see resending of messages.

The behaviour I am seeing is that while the initial cache is being generated, every 10 minutes 5 new messages are grabbed by the client and returned with no ack or nack by my code. This is unexpected. I would expect the deadline of the original 5 messages to be extended up to an hour.

Furthermore, after having processed and acked about 500 of the messages, I would expect around 600 left in the subscription, but I see almost the original 1100. These turn out to be resent duplicates, as I log these in my code. This is also very unexpected.

This is a screenshot from google console after around 500 messages have been processed and acked (ignore the first "hump", that was an aborted test run):

[image]

Am I missing something?

Here is the setup code:

```
  val name = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(ConfigurationValues.ProjectId,
                                        ConfigurationValues.PubSubSubscription)
  val topic = ProjectTopicName.of(ConfigurationValues.ProjectId,
                                  ConfigurationValues.PubSubSubscriptionTopic)
  val pushConfig = PushConfig.newBuilder.build
  val ackDeadlineSeconds = 600
  subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(
    name,
    topic,
    pushConfig,
    ackDeadlineSeconds)

  val flowControlSettings = FlowControlSettings.newBuilder()
      .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(5L)
      .build();

  // create a subscriber bound to the asynchronous message receiver
  val subscriber = Subscriber
    .newBuilder(subscriptionName, new EtlMessageReceiver(spark))
    .setFlowControlSettings(flowControlSettings)
    .setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
    .build
  subscriber.startAsync.awaitRunning()
```

Here is the code in the receiver which runs when a message arrives while the cache is being generated:

```
  if(!BIQConnector.cacheGenerationDone){
    Utilities.logLine(
      s"PubSub message for work item $uniqueWorkItemId ignored as cache is still being generated.")
    return
  }
```

And finally when a message has been processed:

```
  consumer.ack()
  Utilities.logLine(s"PubSub message ${message.getMessageId} for $tableName acknowledged.")

  // Write back to ETL Manager
  Utilities.logLine(
    s"Writing result message back to topic ${etlResultTopic} for table $tableName, $tableDetailsForLog.")
  sendPubSubResult(importTableName, validTableName, importTimestamp, 2, etlResultTopic, stageJobData,
    tableDetailsForLog, "Success", isDeleted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your Spark job using [a Pub/Sub client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) to pull messages? These libraries should indeed keep extending your message deadlines up to the MaxAckExtensionPeriod you specified.

If your job is using a Pub/Sub client library, this is unexpected behavior. You should contact Google Cloud support with your project name, subscription name, client library version, and a sample of the message IDs from the messages you are "returning" without acking. They will be able to investigate further into why you're receiving these resent messages.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Java client library. Ok thanks, I'll contact Google.